# TYPO3 $this->bootstrap->run not load plugin controller

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18 and I am making ajaxDispatcher. I stay on final study. I trying to call `$this->bootstrap->run( '', $this->configuration );` but it get an error. I can't know what this error is exactly. But I'm sure problem in this line.

My $this->configuration is:

```
array(8) {
    ["pluginName"] => string(7) "Piphoto"
    ["vendorName"] => string(5) "Istar"
    ["extensionName"] => string(7) "feFiles"
    ["controller"] => string(5) "Photo"
    ["action"] => string(4) "test"
    ["mvc"] => array(1) {
        ["requestHandlers"] => array(1) {
            ["TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\FrontendRequestHandler"] =>
                  string(48) "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\FrontendRequestHandler"
        }
    }
    ["settings"] => array(2) {
        ["adminemail"] => string(15) "mvnaz@yandex.ru"
        ["pageShowPhotoId"] => string(2) "32"
    }
    ["persistence"] => array(1) {
        ["storagePid"] => string(2) "31"
    }
}
```

Action test is allowed in local_conf. The Vendor is set right, extension name, plugin and controller too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry) 
["extensionName"]=>
  string(7) "fefiles"

fefiles need Fefiles - uppercase!

Thank you all for help! )